# How to change a custom dialog layout depending on it's width?

Tags: android, dialog

After creating a [custom `Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) using a `ListView` and my own implementation of `ListAdapter`, I notice that the width of the dialog changes depending on the device screen size (and perhaps on other factors I'm not aware of).

I'd like to use a different layout for wider dialogs. What are some good ways to get the width of a Dialog, preferably before calling `Dialog.show()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) guide.

What you basicaly need to do is create a layout res folder for each screen size you intend to support:

```
// layouts for various screen sizes
res/layout/my_custom_dialog.xml             // normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_custom_dialog.xml       // small screen size
res/layout-large/my_custom_dialog.xml       // large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_custom_dialog.xml      // extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_custom_dialog.xml // extra large in landscape
```

Comment: While the screen size is useful, isn't really what I need in this situation. True, Dialog views are wider on my tablet than on my phone, but I'd like to query the Dialog width, not the screen width. At this point, I'm not convinced that the screen size and Dialog size are necessarily related.